# Yii2 - Dropdownlist OnChange to Display Other Model Attribute

Tags: yii2

I have these Model Classes

Model:`Subject`

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'subject_id' =>Yii::t('app',  'ID'),
        'subject_title' => Yii::t('app', 'Subject Title'),
    ];
}
```

Model:`Grouping`

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'grouping_id' => Yii::t('app', 'Grouping ID'),
        'grouping_name' => Yii::t('app', 'Grouping Name'),
    ];
}
```

Model:`SubjectGrouping`

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'subject_grouping_id' => 'Subject Grouping ID',
        'subject_grouping_grouping_id' => 'Subject Grouping Grouping ID',
        'subject_grouping_subject_id' => 'Subject Grouping Subject ID',
    ];
}
```

Model:`Exam`

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'exam_id' =>Yii::t('app',  'ID'),
        'exam_name' => Yii::t('app', 'Exam Name'),
    'exam_group_id' => Yii::t('app', 'Exam Group'),
    ];
}
```

Model:`SubjectGrouping` has Foreign Keys from Model: `Grouping` (`subject_grouping_grouping_id`) and Model:`Subject` (`subject_grouping_subject_id`)

In Model:`Exam`, `exam_group_id` relates to `subject_grouping_grouping_id` in Model:`SubjectGrouping`.

**Controller**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Exam();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $model->attributes = $_POST['Exam'];
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } else {
        return $this->render(
            'create', [
                'model' => $model
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
    <?=$form->field($model, 'exam_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => 50, 'placeholder' => 'Enter Exam Name'])?>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
<?=$form->field($model, 'exam_group_id')->widget(
    Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Grouping::find()->all(), 'grouping_id', 'grouping_name'),
        'language' => 'en',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => '--- Select Grouping ---'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ]
    ]
);
?>
</div>
```

[image: Dropdownlist]

From the diagram, how do I achieve these?

1. when Dropdownlist for `exam_group_id` is `onChange` the list of subjects with respect to grouping is displayed using the relationship between Model: `SubjectGrouping` and Model: `Subject`.
2. Others fields such as  `exam_name` (textInput) and exam_group_id (Dropdownlist) should be save into the Model: `Exam`. But the subject list should not be saved. It is only for display purpose.

How do I achieve these?

> I am using `kartik\widgets\Select2` for the dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar code by Kartik extension for state and country data.

here is the code for that.

```
<?php
    //in view use this

    use kartik\widgets\DateTimePicker; // or kartik\select2\Select2
    use kartik\widgets\DepDrop;
    use kartik\widgets\Select2;
?>

<?php
    echo
    $form->field($model, 'country_id')->widget(
        Select2::className(),
        [
            'data' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(common\models\Country::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
            'options' => [
                'id' => 'country_id',
                'prompt' => Yii::t('aspns', 'Select')
            ]
        ]
    );
?>
<?php
    echo
    $form->field($model, 'state_id')->widget(
        DepDrop::classname(),
        [
            'data' => !empty($model->state_id) ? \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(common\models\State::find()->where(['country_id' => $model->country_id])->all(), 'id', 'name') : [],
            'options' => ['id' => 'state_id', 'placeholder' => Yii::t('aspns', 'Select')],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'depends' => ['country_id'],
                'url' => Url::to(['//country/get-states'])
            ]
        ]
    )->label(Yii::t('aspns', 'State'));
?>
```

//  In Controller section you need to do this

```
 public function actionGetStates() {
    $out = [];
    if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
        $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
        if ($parents != null) {
            $country_id = (int)$parents[0];
            $out = State::find()->where(['country_id'=>$country_id])->select(['id', 'name'=>'name'])->asArray()->all();
            return Json::encode(['output'=>$out, 'selected'=>'']);

        }
    }
    return  Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'selected'=>'']);
}
```

Change the code according to your requirement.

Thanks

Comment: this in all aspects is an incorrect implementation of the `DepDrop` you don't provide the data depending on the `model->state_id` as it needs to load data from the ajax call when the parent dropdown triggers change event and the controller suggested code is also incorrect it will raise error in the latest Yii version, you must correct the answer or delete it altogether before you get downvotes.

Comment: I have use this in advanced yii2 .. and it is working...yes ajax call will be there because we need to load data after country select...